# electron - process.env.npm_package* variables missing

Tags: node.js, electron, package.json

I am building an electron application using [electron-boilerplate](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate).

I have some variables that I am keeping in package.json under `config`.  Normally with node, you would be able to access them like `process.env.npm_package_config_variableName`.  However in my electron app I don't see any of the [package.json var bindings](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) in the main process.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Do you have an example of where it is failing, or any error?
 Is everything spelled properly when calling `process.env.npm_package_config_variableName`

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing a similar issue using the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module.

Interestingly, when I run 'electron .' the process.env variables work as expected with `require('dotenv').config();`

They are only not configured properly when I package my app using [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager) and open the the app as `<appName>-darwin-x64`.

Comment: Same here :( I think I'll have to move my env configs to a JS file